# Sklearn, inconsistent numbers of samples using sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I'm using the sklearn [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) implementation for multiclass SVM.

My model is supposed to have multiple outputs so I'm using One-Hot-Enconding on my labels ([MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)).

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=classes, sparse_output=True)
y_train = mlb.transform(y_train)
mlb.fit(y_train)
```

This gives me a vector of labels per sample, y_train is a csr_matrix of shape (n_samples, n_classes) specifically (18171, 17).

My training set is in the form of a scipy [csc_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) of shape (n_samples, n_feature) specifically (18171, 1001).

```
m_o_SVC = MultiOutputClassifier(SVC(C=0.1, kernel='linear', probability=True), n_jobs=-1)
m_o_SVC.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This trains several classifiers each with a slice of the labels.

But I get this Warning:

```
"DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel()."
```

And this error:

```
"Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [18171, 1]"
```

If I don't use a sparse matrix for the labels everything works but I am not sure whether using a dense label representation will cause the algorithm to work with dense matrices (with a loss of performance).

Also, I don't understand the problem since the shapes are consistent.

Is this a problem with sklearn?

Comment: In your above code, you use `mlb.transform()` before the `mlb.fit()`. I hope thats not the case in real code.  Also please post the full stack trace of error and re check the shape of `X_train` and `y_train` by printing their values just before you train them.